# Magento: Unable to show custom block

Tags: php, magento

I followed this tutorial to create the custom block in magento

http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/how-to-creating-your-own-custom-block-in-magento

But nothing is showed when I open up home page or any other page. I have searched alot on web but unable to solve the issue.

The above tutorial did not mention where to create layout.xml file but I have created it at:

app\design\frontend\gravitywell\example\layout\layout.xml  ---It has just following code:

```
<block type="gravitywellexample/menu" name="menu" as="menu" template="gravitywell/menu.phtml" />
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, Magento has its [own StackExchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: can you share your code.so that if error is their can be found.

Comment: You can view all the code in mentioned article. I followed the same. I just only created my layout file which I have mentioned in the questsion. Thanks

Comment: Is your module telling Magento to load `layout.xml`?  Try renaming it to `local.xml` since magento will look for this automatically.

Comment: I have renamed it to local.xml but no benenfit... How to check if magento is loading the module or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use local.xml, but then the question becomes what handle tags to put it inside of i.e. where do you want it to show up.  When using a 2column-right layout, I can position it inside of the right column on the product page this way:

```
<catalog_product_view>      
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="gravitywellexample/menu" name="menu" as="menu" template="gravitywell/example/menu.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

my template is stored in a slightly different folder.
hth, sconnie

Comment: What will happen when the magento will be updated? The code written in 2column-right will be lost?

Comment: local.xml should be in your /app/code/design/frontend/packagename/themename/layout/local.xml.  This is your package/theme and won't be overwritten by an upgrade.  The code is not in 2column-right.phtml.  It's in local.xml.